# Network stopped working after KVM installation on 21.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, kvm-virtualization, 21.10

I just installed Android Studio, and it recommended that I install KVM.

So I did, using plain `apt install ...`. And now my network doesn't work anymore.

It seems the network manager isn't running, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

I guess the network manager not running is why I don't have any network devises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling the `network-manager` packet.

Since the KVM installation forced its uninstallation and I didn't have the `network-manager` packet cached, I had to download the packet and its requirements to a phone, and then use USB file-sharing to transfer the files to the computer for explicit installation.